# "Flushed out" or "Fleshed out"

Tags: pronunciation

I think this is a mispronunciation, but I'm not sure...

Is "To thoroughly vet something" to "flush it out" or "flesh it out"?

"flush" makes intuitive sense, but I've heard "fleshed out" plenty of times too.

Comment: You "flush out" birds to make them fly out so you can shoot them. You "flesh out" all the details by spelling them all out. (you might do that to vet the process, but vetting is not the primary meaning of to "flesh out"). Yes, these are [eggcorns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) for each other.

Comment: "eggcorns" THANK YOU... I couldn't remember that word

Comment: They are metaphorically close ("flushing out" details like pigeons to be shot)

Comment: Mitch you should make this your answer.

Comment: The image underlying "flesh out" is that of putting flesh on the bare skeleton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper usage (by dictionary definitions) are both metaphorical:

- You "flush out" birds to make them fly out so you can shoot them. This can metaphorically mean that you are trying to make many small unnoticed things more apparent.
- You "flesh out" something, as Stoney B notes, by putting extra flesh on something bare boned. Metaphorically, you're filling in the details to a bigger framework, adding a number of smaller items to a bigger thing.

Because the metaphors are close and the sounds are too, these are often used interchangeably. Since I feel that neither is primary, I suggest that these are [eggcorns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) (weak malapropisms) for each other

To thoroughly vet something is to analyse all the details and approve them. (the approval is the most salient, not necessarily the detail part. So vetting is not really what fleshing out or flushing out is about.